# fast infix search and count on a 40 million rows table postgresql

Tags: performance, postgresql, case

I'm new to database administration, but I need to create a database view, while the db admin requires it to run in 5 mins or less. My database is PostgreSQL 9.1.1 on RedHat4.4 linux 64-bit. I'm unsure about the hardware specifications. One of the tables is 40million rows. From the table, I have a column of directory paths from which I must group by about 20 string patterns and count its occurrences. The string pattern requires infix search, as it could be somewhere in the middle or end of the path. The string pattern also has a priority, as in when %str1% then 'str1', when %str2% then 'str2', and both str1, str2, str3, etc can occur on the same path, i.e.

```
path 
/usr/myblock/str1/str2
/usr/myblock/something/str2
/usr/myblock/str1/something/str3
```

What I did so far was to build a table out of CASE statements then join it back to the original table by LIKE, then SELECT id, pattern, count(pattern). The query runtime was terrible, taking 5mins to retrieve from 5.5K rows. My query looks like this:

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT CASE 
WHEN path ~ '^/usr/myblock/(.*)str1(.*)' THEN 'str1'
WHEN path ~ '^/usr/myblock/(.*)str2$' THEN 'str2'
WHEN path ~ '^/usr/myblock/(.*)str3$' THEN 'str3'
.... --multiple other case conditions
WHEN path ~ '^/usr/myblock/' THEN 'others'
ELSE 'n/a'
END as flow
FROM mega_t WHERE left(path,13)='/usr/myblock/' limit 5)
SELECT id, a.flow, count(*) AS flow_count FROM a 
JOIN mega_t ON path LIKE '%' || a.flow || '%'
WHERE (some_conditions) AND to_timestamp(test_runs.created_at::double precision) 
> ('now'::text::date - '1 mon'::interval) --collect last 1 month's results only
GROUP BY id, a.flow;
```

My expected output for that simple case would be:

```
id | flow | flow_count
1  | str1 | 2
2  | str2 | 1
```

What is a better way to search for substrings like this and count occurrences? I can't use ts_stat, nor 'SELECT count(path) WHERE path LIKE %str1%' because of the if-else priority it needs. I read about creating trigram indexes, but I think that is overkill for my patterns. I hope this question is clear and useful. Another thing I should add is that the 40million rows table is updated frequently every few seconds or minutes while the view will be accessed every eight hours daily.

Comment: Is using OnInsert and OnDelete triggers on the original an option? So you could count the occurrences on modifications of the original table and store it in another one.

Comment: Try [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html). Also I'd be concerned that the `limit 5` completely ignores your if-else prioritizing. You'd need to `order by` the  computed priority, not just having it in the select list.

Comment: @UweAllner, do you mean I create a table summarizing the count in another table, with triggers, and then create a view of this table? I guess it should be permissible by my admin. Is that how it's usually done, for these 'summary snapshots'?

Comment: @DanielVerite, I just realized my database didn't install the pg_trgm extension.

Comment: If I use the trigger and create table method, how would I first create the initial table with all the data collected so far, then add on triggers to continue building that table?

Comment: For the intial filling of the summary table you don't have the time limit, so it may take its time; after that, every insert and delet on the original table will update the statistics in the summary in very short time; perhaps you will need no view upon that, but can use it directly.

Comment: I just remembered another point which is that my 40mil rows table is frequently updated while the view is accessed every 8 hrs. Would triggers be optimum for such an arrangement?

Comment: When it is accessed so sparsely, then why the requirements for fast access? Impatient admin? ;) As long as the trigger don't slow down inserting dramatically (as they won't, I suppose), it will still be a good solution.